# How can I prevent virtual methods from being mocked?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, abstract-class, rhino-mocks

We have a base class providing some default implementation for `INotifyPropertyChanged` (this class is used by many other classes and cannot be easily changed):

```
public class ObservableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // this is virtual so derived classes can override it (rarely used, but it is used)
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have an interface and an abstract base class deriving from `ObservableBase` and implementing that interface providing some default implementations (mainly for the properties):

```
public interface INamedTrigger
{
    string Name { get; }
    void Execute();
}

public abstract class ObservableNamedTriggerBase : ObservableBase, INamedTrigger
{
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    public abstract void Execute();
}
```

Now I want to unit test the default implementations of `ObservableNamedTriggerBase` (using NUnit and RhinoMocks):

```
[TestFixture]
public class ObservableNamedTriggerBaseTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestNameChangeRaisesPropertyChanged()
    {
        var prop = "";
        var mocks = new MockRepository();
        var namedBase = mocks.PartialMock<ObservableNamedTriggerBase>();
        namedBase.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => prop = e.PropertyName;
        namedBase.Name = "Foo";
        Assert.AreEqual("Name", prop);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this test fails as Rhino seems to override the virtual `OnPropertyChanged` method from `ObservableBase`.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732611/rhino-mocking-classes-and-not-overriding-virtual-methods) and the [Rhino docs](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks.ashx) indicate that `PartialMock` should exactly **not** do this. On the other hand the answer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806073/why-does-my-partial-mock-have-all-virtual-methods-mocked-even-if-no-expectation) indicates that Rhino always overrides virtual methods regardless of the type of mock.

So is the documentation wrong? And how do I go about testing this correctly?

**Update**: If I create my own mock class providing dummy implementations for just the abstract methods then the test passes but I'd like to use Rhino mocks to save me the work of exactly doing that.

Comment: have you debugged it? and saw what was the problem

Comment: @DanHunex: I have debugged it and can see that it does not enter the `OnPropertyChanged` method in `ObservableBase` .

Comment: then what value did you get for prop?

Comment: @DanHunex: `prop` is the empty string (with which it was initialized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which version are you using, but it seems that you're mixing RR (*Record-Replay*) syntax usage with more recent AAA (*Arrange-Act-Assert*). Basically, doing this:

```
var repo = new MockRepository();
var mock = repo.PartialMock<ObservableNamedTriggerBase>();
```

Requires you also to at least do this:

```
repo.ReplayAll();
```

Lack of which, will cause mocks to misbehave (a call to `repo.Record()` might be needed if you're setting expectations/stubbing too). This is unnecessary effort considering modern syntax is available ([starting with](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2008/05/rhino-mocks-35-goodbye-record-and.html) [Rhino 3.5](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#WhatsNewinRhinoMocksDF)):

```
// no repository needed at all
var mock = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<ObservableNamedTriggerBase>();
```

New static methods on `MockRepository` are taking care of the record-replay setup under the hood.

Comment: Strange, I'm almost sure I tried the `ReplayAll` before and it didn't work, but now it does. AAA syntax seems nicer though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to create a testing subclass where the method is not overridable.

```
public abstract class TestingObservableNamedTriggerBase : ObservableNamedTriggerBase {
  protected override sealed void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
    base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
  }
}
```

And then test it through this subclass.

I haven't tested if this works though...

Comment: Yes, this works. Using `mocks.PartialMock<TestingObservableNamedTriggerBase>()` makes the test pass. I like this better over providing my own mock object. Still seems more like a workaround for a bug (or feature?).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CallBase` boolean property to tell moq whether uses original virtual methods or override them with default values. As it said in its summary for the property:

> CallBase Summary: Whether the base member virtual implementation will be called for mocked classes if no setup is matched. Defaults to false.

So use this:

`mock.CallBase = true;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CallOriginalMethod](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Method+Options+Interface.ashx) method of Rhinomocks to call the original method.

```
namedBase.Expect(x => x.OnPropertyChanged(Arg<string>.Is.Anything))
         .CallOriginalMethod(OriginalCallOptions.NoExpectation);
```

If the class under the test is included other assembly from the test assembly, you may need to make the `OnPropertyChanged` method `protected internal` and to add `InternalVisibleToAttribute` for the test assembly.

Also as you already know, add `InternalVisibleToAttribute("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")` to mock internal types.

Comment: Hm, I don't really like changing the access modifier for no other purpose but to satisfy a unit testing framework. I'll test it tomorrow.